# How to call many functions with requireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, requirejs

I have two files: main.js and events.js.

In main.js i have defined some functions, which look's like this:

```
define(["jquery"], function() {

    var a =  {
       function_a: function(){
         some_actions;
       }
    }

    var b =  {
       function_b: function(){
         some_actions;
       }
    }

    return a, b;
});
```

and in events.js i have some calls for this functions:

```
require(['jquery','app/main'], function($, a){
    selector.on('click', function(){
        a.function_a();
    });
});

require(['jquery','app/main'], function($, b){
    selector.on('click', function(){
        b.function_b();
    });
});
```

Something is wrong because i can't call more than one of this functions, can anybody help?

Comment: `return a, b;` - this line doesn't work like you seem to think.

Comment: ok, why? do i need create some array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `return a,b` which is invalid statement you need to return an object for example:
`return {'a':a, 'b':b}`

Then in your code you can write:

```
require(['jquery','app/main'], function($, obj){
    selector.on('click', function(){
        obj.a.function_a();
        obj.b.function_b();
    });
});
```

You could use also array. Then return will be `return [a,b]` and in require function:

```
require(['jquery','app/main'], function($, obj){
    selector.on('click', function(){
        obj[0].function_a();
        obj[1].function_b();
    });
});
```

Comment: ok, but this return should be `var obj = {
        'fn': a,
        'fn': b
    };
    return obj;` ?

Comment: you cannot have same id in JSON. You could use array. I will add update

Comment: A minor nitpick: `return a,b` is not a invalid statement per se - it's just meaningless, as only `b` value is returned. The fact that `a` is evaluated too is obviously of little use. ) But overall, very nice explanation, +1 from me.